# Android stack. How to use flags in this case?

Tags: android, android-intent

**Here is my situation:**
I have MAIN activity, four TOOLBAR activities, that user can launch from always visible toolbar and other activites.

**What I want:**
App start with MAIN Activity. Then user goes to Main -> TOOLBARActivity (1) - OtherActivity(1) - OtherActivity(2) - ... - TOOLBARActivity(2).
When launching the TOOLBARActivity(2) I need to clear all stack from Main till TOOLBARActivity(2). So if now user will press the back button, he will return to MAIN Activity.

So, I simply need find the way to clear all activities in stack except the first one.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to your second Activity you can use like this :

```
intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
StartActivity(intent);
```

this flag clears top of Activity stack

Comment: CLEAR_TOP do nothing. If I startActivity with Intent flag CLEAR_TOP, than I still can go back to previous activity